# Where is the Compose Scylladb SSL certificate?

Tags: compose-db, scylla

I'm trying to connect to my scylladb 1.7.4 instance using the connection string provided for me in the compose overview section of the management UI:

```
$ cqlsh --ssl portal-xxxx.ibm-343.composedb.com 19228 -u scylla -p XXXX --cqlversion=3.3.1
```

However, the response is:

> Validation is enabled; SSL transport factory requires a valid certfile to be specified. Please provide path to the certfile in [ssl] section as 'certfile' option in /Users/snowch/.cassandra/cqlshrc (or use [certfiles] section) or set SSL_CERTFILE environment variable

Where can I get access to the Compose SSL certificate so that I can connect with:

```
$ SSL_CERTFILE=/path/to/scylla_certfile cqlsh --ssl portal-xxxx-0.csnow-scylla-45.ibm-343.composedb.com 19228 -u scylla -p XXXX --cqlversion=3.3.1
```

I have seen the option `SSL_VALIDATE=false` in the [documentation](https://help.compose.com/docs/scylla-connecting-to) however, I don't want to disable SSL validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information is further down in the documentation in the section https://help.compose.com/docs/scylla-and-certificates.

My confusion was because I was drawn to the information on ssl (#2) because of the issue I had encountered and as such I jumped over the section on full configuration for cqlsh (#1):

> **Cqlsh Command Line**
>
> The Cqlsh Command Line panel contains three cqlsh commands, each of which connect to the three Compose portals. Full details on obtaining cqlsh and configuring it are available in [Scylla and cqlsh](https://help.compose.com/docs/scylla-and-cqlsh). (#1)
>
> The displayed command include required flags (`--ssl` and `--cqlversion`). If the command is preceded by setting the environment variable `SSL_VALIDATE=false`, then no further configuration is needed. (#2)

I think this section would be a bit clearer if it was re-ordered:

> **Cqlsh Command Line**
>
> The Cqlsh Command Line panel contains three cqlsh commands, each of which connect to the three Compose portals.
>
> The displayed command include required flags (`--ssl` and `--cqlversion`). If the command is preceded by setting the environment variable `SSL_VALIDATE=false`, then no further configuration is needed.
>
> Full details on obtaining cqlsh and configuring it are available in [Scylla and cqlsh](https://help.compose.com/docs/scylla-and-cqlsh).  This section includes information on configuring cqlsh to use ssl.